# Not able to install quandl

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning

Using the following command

```
pip install quandl
```

Getting the following error:

```
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-i9EhxV/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8wUBuY-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-i9EhxV/cryptography/
```

Comment: You are missing oppenssl development headers. On Debian/Ubuntu the package is probably called `libssl-dev`.

Comment: Btw. if you want to do machine learning in python, anaconda python might be a good candidate for you to avoid such troubles with system dependencies.

Comment: @languitar .. TY a lot.. it got installed :-)

Comment: @languitar could you tell me how to install anaconda python.

Comment: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: it got installed.. but when i'm running the python script consisting of only
"import Quandl"
its showing error
"module not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you have to install ---libssl-dev--- and you have to write quandl all lowercase (not Uppercase as you did)..."import quandl".

Answer (score 1):

You are missing oppenssl development headers. On Debian/Ubuntu the package is probably called `libssl-dev`.

Comment: it got installed.. but when i'm running the python script consisting of only "import Quandl" its showing error "module not found"

Comment: Just see the other answer... Anyway, as the original question is answered, it would be nice if you could accept one of the answer.